# Perl: how to extract from "d days, h:mm:ss"

Tags: perl, date, datetime, extract

I wish to do math with a device uptime in this format "d days, h:mm:ss" (or "h:mm:ss" if device not up longer than a day but I can program how to check for that)

My ask is a routine how to extract the `d`, `h`, `mm` and `ss` from the string so I can do calculation with it (using DateTime which I found here too)

Comment: `DateTime::Format::Duration` would be one way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved with a simple regex with some capturing groups.

This will take a time formatted as "d days, h:mm:ss" and will give you the days, hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Define a random time
my $time = '4 days, 03:44:23';

# Extract the data from the time
my ($days, $h, $m, $s) = $time =~ m/([0-9]+)\sdays,\s([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/;

# Print the output
print 'time: '.$time."\n\n";
print 'days: '.$days."\n";
print 'h   : '.$h."\n";
print 'm   : '.$m."\n";
print 's   : '.$s."\n";
```

For more information on how to use regular expressions you may find this helpful: [perlre (regular expression tutorial)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Also since you're new to Perl I will add that you should **ALWAYS** add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your code.  It will stop you from making silly mistakes (like attempting to use an undefined variable for example) and save you a lot of headaches.

---

You can also validate whether you have good data by putting the match in an `if` statement.  It is good to get in the habit of doing this.

```
my ($days, $h, $m, $s);
if ($time =~ m/([0-9]+)\sdays,\s([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/) {
    ($days, $h, $m, $s) = ($1, $2, $3, $4)
}
else {
    die "Invalid date format encountered!";
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! That is what I was looking for indeed

Comment: Yes, been there too - thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Since this looks like a teachable moment, I'm going to add that tjwrona1992's regex

```
my ($days, $h, $m, $s) = $time =~ m/([0-9]+)\sdays,\s([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/;
```

could be written using the /x modifier to allow whitespace and comments to make it more digestible to human consumers:

```
    my ($days, $h, $m, $s) = $time =~ m/
              ([0-9]+) \s days, # $1 will be days
              \s
              ([0-9]+) :        # $2 = hours     
              ([0-9]+) :        # $3 = minutes
              ([0-9]+)          # $4 = seconds

        /x or die "the regex did not match '$time'";
```

Comment: And thank you too ! I can choose now